# PlayFramework: multiple routes file in project

Tags: scala, playframework

Is that possible to have multiple conf/routes file in the play project? i.e:

```
   -> conf/ 
           routes
           utils.routes
           user.routes
```

Or is the are any work around for this? 
as I understand conf/routes will be compiled and validation will be run etc ..and would assume it is possible to override this logic somehow.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try to split it with the module approach as described in [the official documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/SBTSubProjects#Splitting-the-route-file).

> It’s also possible to split the route file into smaller pieces. This
>   is a very handy feature if you want to create a robust, reusable
>   multi-module play application.

In a nutshell, you can group your app code into one or more modules, each with own route file(s). You can then include the smaller route files into the global route file like in the following example:

**conf/routes:**

```
GET /index                  controllers.HomeController.index()

->  /admin admin.Routes

GET     /assets/*file       controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

**modules/admin/conf/admin.routes:**

```
GET /index                  controllers.admin.HomeController.index()

GET /assets/*file           controllers.Assets.at(path="/public/lib/myadmin", file)
```

Comment: works perfect, exactly what I was looking for! thank you,

Answer (score 1):

Building on top of javierhe's answer.
If you are using a sbt single project and DI and still want to use multiple routes file, you can do so like below.
No need of sbt multi project setup.

```
conf/ 
     routes
     admin.routes
```

conf/routes:

```
GET /index                  controllers.HomeController.index()

->  /admin admin.Routes
```

conf/admin.routes:

```
GET /index                  controllers.admin.HomeController.index()
```

And in the application loader,
add below into build routes.

```
val adminRouter: admin.Routes = {
        val prefix = "/"
        wire[admin.Routes] //replace it with constructor if you do manual DI
}
val router: Routes = {
        val prefix = "/"
        wire[Routes] //replace it with constructor if you do manual DI
}
```

Tested with play 2.8.x and macwire.